# Map Google Cloud Functions with Custom DNS

Tags: dns, google-cloud-functions

I have Cloud Functions.. which i want to map with .custom DNS.
I have my DNS setup, but after doing that it is not resolving to my Cloudfunctions.
It is Reaching to google server though. not sure if i need to do any configuration within my google project to make it work

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/36155827) to integrate custom domains to Cloud functions

Answer (score 3):

If you want to attach a custom domain to Cloud Functions, the only supported way to do that is through [Firebase Hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting).  You can [configure Firebase Hosting to proxy requests to Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions), and you can also [connect a custom domain](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain) to Firebase Hosting.  Between those two configurations, you can effectively use a custom domain to serve Cloud Functions endpoints.